# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, then prove that (1), (2) and (3) holds.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Below is the way I did it.

[image]

[image]

Can someone verify my proof? Let me know if there is any concern or I need better notation and style somewhere. Appreciate your help & support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$ the idea is fine, if $Y$ is a subset of $(X,d)$:

$$\forall y \in Y: \forall r>0: B_{d_Y}(y, r) = B_d(y,r) \cap Y\tag{a}$$

which shows that all $d_Y$-balls are $Y$-open, so $\mathcal{T}_{d_Y} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$. And if $O \subseteq$ is $Y$-open, $O=O' \cap Y$ for some open $O'$ of $X$. Then for $y \in O (\subseteq O')$ we find $r>0$ with $B_d(y,r) \subseteq O'$ and then $(a)$ tells us (intersecting this inclusion on both sides by $Y$) that $B_{d_Y}(y,r) \subseteq O' \cap Y=O$ and so $O \in \mathcal{T}_{d_Y}$ (all $y \in O$ are $d_Y$-interior points) and the reverse inclusion of topologies also holds.

In your proof I don't see the two proofs of inclusion that clearly.

$(2)$ is fine, but add an argument why $B_d(x,\varepsilon) \cap B_d(y, \varepsilon) = \emptyset$: suppose $z \in X$ is in their intersection, so $d(x,z) < \varepsilon$ and $d(y,z) < \varepsilon$ and

$$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) < \varepsilon + \varepsilon = 2\varepsilon = d(x,y)$$

contradiction. Show that you actually use the properties of a metric!

With $(3)$ the idea is fine, but more details: If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, for each $n \in \Bbb N$ pick $a_n \in A$ such that $a_n \in B_d(x, \frac{1}{n})\cap (A\setminus \{x\})$, or $d(a_n, x) < \frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n \neq x$. (Do mention that $a_n \neq x$ is possible, as it's part of the question's requirement, and it easily follows from being a limit point of $A$).

The proof that $a_n \to x$ is then simply: let $\varepsilon >0$ and pick $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$ and then for all $n \ge N$ we have $d(a_n, x) < \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$, as required. (Do add that final "prooflet", unless you have a separate lemma to fall back on.)

The reverse again needs the remark that all $a_n \neq x$ and so $a_k \in B(x,\varepsilon) \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$, the requirement for being a limit point of $A$.

Comment: For Q1, its fine. Although I am struggling with showing the reverse side but I guess even if I dont show it its good. For part (2), you used the opposite of Triangle inequality of metric spaces which is good n works well. But I have doubts in part (3), pick N such that $\frac{1}{N}$ < $\epsilon$, is it $\mathbb{N}$ or just capital N ? Also, what is final prooflet, is it the last part?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun For Q2 I don't use the "opposite" of triangle inequality, just the standard triangle inequality, so I don't see your point..  For Q3, by prooflet I meant what I added to show $a_n \to x$, which you don't show, just claim. And I mean $N$ (an index large enough), not $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ok got it, for Q2 that's wat u used but you used it the other way (i.e. if a <= b, you said that b >= a) which works perfectly. thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I said $d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+ d(y,z)$, which I think is not reversed?

Comment: yeah this is wat I was talking about.